# How can i convert user enter number into list in python? Like user entered 56989 and i want these number separately in list{5,6,9,8,9}

Tags: python, indexing, reverse

Because i wanna make a  program for reverse of number entered by user .So after getting number into list,will do indexing to get reversal of that number entered by user.If Yes so How??or No so what is the other method.

```
#reverse of a number

num = int(input("Enter a number"))
list = [num]
print(list)
list[3]
print(list)
```

Comment: `print(''.join(reversed(input("Enter a number"))))`?

Answer (score 0):

use list() amd map() function. use `a[::-1]` to reverse the list.

```
a =list(map(int,input()))
print(a)
print(a[::-1])
print(a[2])
```

Input:

```
56989
```

Output:

```
[5,6,9,8,9]  /normal list /
[9,8,9,6,5]  /reversed list /
 9           /accesing the reversed list /
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user entered "12345", doing

```
my_list = list(input("Enter a number"))
```

Would give you a list `['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']` (of strings)

If you just want to reverse it and print it, there are several ways. To reverse it we can `my_list = my_list[::-1]` for example. The more readable way we can use to reverse it "in-place":

```
my_list.reverse()
```

Either way, we now have a list that is `['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']`

You can just print that, but I assume you want to turn it back into a string, we can do that with

```
my_str = ''.join(my_list)
```

Putting it all together:

```
my_list = list(input("Enter a number"))
my_list.reverse()
my_str = ''.join(my_list)
print(my_str)
```

Would print the reverse of anything the user entered (doesn't have to be numbers, there's a whole other verification we need for that). As was mentioned by @FraggaMuffin in a comment, this can all be done in one line (by using the built-in `reversed` function, avoiding the list altogether):

```
print(''.join(reversed(input("Enter a number"))))
```

Notice however the most important thing, we didn't use the word `list` as a variable, because that would destroy the built-in `list`, that's why it's called `my_list` in my example, same with `str` and `my_str`

I hope this helps you